# Android AsynkTask in loop infinite

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a AsynkTask in loop, when finishes the onPostExecute I want to "restart" the same AsynkTask.

Any knows how to make this?

Comment: yes you can but..this gives you StackOverFlowException after some time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call this `new myAsynctask.execute();` at the last line of the onPostExecute()

```
protected void onPostExecute(){

new myAsynctask.execute();

}
```

Comment: If the asynch process does not strongly rely on the class fields I would advise to call this.execute() to avoid unnesessary memory allocation.

Comment: doing this.execute(); it gives me java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.

Comment: did you specify new keyword in front of your Asynctask name.

Comment: well... using new MyAsynkTask.execute() helps me! Thaks all.